# I'm trying to write a regular expression for C#

Tags: c#, regex

My objective is to find begin and end pattern and remove it from a long string

```
{BEGIN:781}{hopi_docgen4}{sub_chronic_conditions_hpi}{END:}{OPh_cc_docgen}{END:621}{BEGIN:768}{cc_reviewed} {cc_rev_prov}{END:768}
```

**Required regx should satisfy this =>
begin and end followed by a full colon and then followed by the whole number and all these enclosed in curly braces like this {} and this must be working irrespective of the case**

```
{Begin:100} or {end:112} or {BEGIN:105} or {END:398}
```

Currently my solution is this

```
\b{begin:[0-1][0-1][0-1]}\b
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looks like a homework. We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: In the posting guidelines (please read before posting) `Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.`

Comment: This is my first regex experiment that's why i didn't put it
\b{begin:[0-1]}\b

Comment: Regex begin = new Regex(@"(\{)(BEGIN\:)[0-9][0-9][0-9](\})",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            sentence = begin.Replace(sentence,"");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a single regex replacement:

```
public string FindMacroType(string sentence)
{
    return Regex.Replace(sentence, @"(?i){(?:END|BEGIN):[0-9]{3}}", "");
}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%7b%28%3f%3aEND%7cBEGIN%29%3a%5b0-9%5d%7b3%7d%7d&i=%7bBEGIN%3a781%7d%7bhopi_docgen4%7d%7bsub_chronic_conditions_hpi%7d%7bEND%3a%7d%7bOPh_cc_docgen%7d%7bEND%3a621%7d%7bBEGIN%3a768%7d%7bcc_reviewed%7d+%7bcc_rev_prov%7d%7bEND%3a768%7d&r=)

**Pattern details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `{` - a literal `{` (no need to escape, but you may)
- `(?:END|BEGIN)` - either `end` or `begin`
- `:` - a colon
- `[0-9]{3}` - 3 ASCII digits (if there can be 1 or more digits, just replace `{3}` limiting quantifier with a `+` quantifier that matches 1 or more occurrences)
- `}` - a literal `}` (no need escaping).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the Negative Votes;
I have found my answer;

```
public string FindMacroType(string sentence)
{

    Regex begin = new Regex(@"(\{)(BEGIN\:)[0-9][0-9][0-9](\})",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    sentence = begin.Replace(sentence,"");

    Regex end = new Regex(@"(\{)(END\:)[0-9][0-9][0-9](\})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    sentence = end.Replace(sentence, "");

    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: The code only replace the string when its the first BEGIN/END in original string.  My code replace any block.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion Regex is over used.  It should only be used when a string method will not work or becomes too complicated.  In this case I think a string method is better :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "{BEGIN:781}{hopi_docgen4}{sub_chronic_conditions_hpi}{END:}{OPh_cc_docgen}{END:621}{BEGIN:768}{cc_reviewed} {cc_rev_prov}{END:768}";
            string output = RemovePattern(input, 781);
        }

        static string RemovePattern(string input, int id)
        {
            string output = "";
            string beginPattern = string.Format("{0}BEGIN:{1}{2}", "{", id.ToString(), "}");
            string endPattern = string.Format("{0}END:{1}{2}", "{", id.ToString(), "}");


            int beginIndex = input.IndexOf(beginPattern);
            int endIndex = input.IndexOf(endPattern);
            if (endIndex == -1)
            {
                endPattern = "{END:}";
                endIndex = input.IndexOf(endPattern, beginIndex);
            }
            int lengthEnd = endPattern.Length;
            if ((beginIndex >= 0) && (endIndex >= 0))
            {
                int stringLength = (endIndex + lengthEnd) - beginIndex;

                output = input.Substring(0, beginIndex) + input.Substring(endIndex + lengthEnd);

            }

            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, This doesn't work at all; The reason we don't know the int id.
That's why we need a regex

Comment: Then you can use Regex in the RemovePattern method to get END.  Sometimes a mixture of string and regex is needed.  I'm not against regex, but it is not as efficient as a string method.

Comment: I wasn't sure initially if the missing index was a typo.  Fixed code to work with missing index.  Assumed the missing index was first END after the BEGIN.

Comment: Thanks for the help;